# How is Git listening for changes from the editor during a merge conflict?

Tags: git, bash

When I'm working on a merge conflict in Git, my specified editor pops up and I'm able to edit the Git merge message. When I close the file the Git merge process continues.

How is that done? I would like to do something similar in a bash script. Would you create a temporary file and listen for changes on this file? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash, it would look something like this:

```
# Launch editor. 'editor' is a fake command shown as example.
editor -f '/path/to/file'

returnCode=$?

# Ensure the process exited without error.
if [[ $returnCode == "0" ]] ; then
   # Take action...
fi
```

---

Git creates a subprocess that opens up the editor and then waits for that subprocess to finish. When the subprocess is terminated due to the user closing the editor, it checks the file for uncommented text. For example, look at [git's launch_editor](https://github.com/git/git/blob/709ca730f8e093005cc882bfb86c0ca9c83d345b/editor.c) function. It uses `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` as the file to read from.

Answer (score 0):

An excellent script that utilises **vimdiff** to prompt the user to resolve merge conflicts is available [**here**](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/A_better_Vimdiff_Git_mergetool).

[image: using vimdiff on git merge conflicts]

Going through the [**source of the script**](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/A_better_Vimdiff_Git_mergetool#The_diffconflicts_script) should help you understand how its done.